# Aplication scope variables in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: dependency-injection, global-variables, zend-framework2, zend-locale

I want have an store of variables visibles for all application (application space).
I want it because I need access to $locale variable from all views for translate my multilanguage web.

I know in ZF1 there was a ZEND_REGISTRY class, but it has been  removed.

How I can do the same feature in ZF2?
Does it serve DI class (dependency Injector) for done this function?

I have listened also anything about create service factories for classes that have dependencies, and to use the ServiceManager then to manage all dependencies.

I need an example because I've never worked with DI, factories nor ServiceManager.

Answer (score 1):

Variables visible to your whole application are no better than globals and, in this case, you don't need to use them.

ZF2 has the [I18n](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html) class as one of the core classes.

If you download and set up the [skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) you will find an example of translation in ZF2 already up and running.

There is a nice explanation [here](http://samminds.com/2012/09/zend-framework-2-translate-i18n-locale/).

Comment: Sorry for delay of response. Your link has served me very much. Thank you!!

Comment: @josepmra Just wondering why you changed your mind about accepting this answer. Did it not work for you?